# UPDATE MySQL query error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to achieve this query but I got an error:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang
SET name=(select name from ps_product_lang_backup where id_lang=2)
WHERE id_lang = 3
```

But I got the `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Probably I must use JOIN but I'm really new to MySQL and cannot do myself.

What i'm trying to do is simple: i have in my database 3 languages, wish to copy data from one language (english id_lang 2) to paste in another (russian, id_lang 3)

Comment: You need to provide more info about ps_product_lang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the table also has a `product_id` column that is unique for a product.

You need to tell the database to pick the english name *for the same product*.

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang
SET name=(select name from ps_product_lang_backup 
           where id_lang=2 
             and ps_product_lang.product_id = ps_product_lang_backup.product_id)
WHERE id_lang = 3
```

Comment: Yea you assume right, and everybody here gave to me the right solution :) Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2):

I'll try my best to answer this 
after looking to your query it is clear that `(select name from ps_product_lang_backup where id_lang=2`) has more then one result that's why it's causing you the error. Now, to fix this you can do two things.

1. Either you can delete one record with the same `id_lang`(easy one).
2. OR, you can change your subquery like this:

   select name from ps_product_lang_backup where id_lang=2 LIMIT 1

which will change your query like this:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang SET name=(select name from ps_product_lang_backup where id_lang=2 LIMIT 1) WHERE id_lang = 3
```

Hope this help

Comment: That's not solution ..user want to update multiple rows through another table

Comment: I was trying to solve the error rather providing him the entire solution

Answer (score 0):

Here it means that your `SELECT Query` Return more than two results Try this

```
SET name=(select name from ps_product_lang_backup where id_lang=2 LIMIT 1)
```